# another "dereferencing point to incomplete type" question

Tags: c, struct, dereference

i checked and didnt find any material which can help me so i had to ask. this is the code:

list.h:

```
typedef struct List_t *List;
```

list.c:

```
#include "list.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>


typedef struct Item_t
{
    struct Item_t* next;
    ListElement data;
}*Item;

typedef struct List_t
{
    Item head;
    Item iterator;
    CopyListElement copyFunc;
    FreeListElement freeFunc;
};
```

list_example_test.c:

```
#include "list.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
ListElement copyA(ListElement a)
{
    return a;
}
void destroyA(ListElement a)
{
}
bool testListCreate();
bool testListCopy()
{
    List list1=listCreate(copyA,destroyA);
    listInsertFirst(list1,(void*)6);
    listInsertFirst(list1,(void*)2);
    listInsertFirst(list1,(void*)1);
    List list2=listCopy(list1);
    listClear(list1);
    if(list2->head==NULL) //here is the error!!
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

the last piece of code is supposed to check whether the listCopy() function works. the compiler recognizes the name List and when i type "list2->" it even suggests to autocomplete with the fields of List(in this instance i chose "list2->head".
what is causing the problem and how to fix it? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`List_t` is an incomplete type as far as `list_example_test.c` is concerned.  This is actually a common idiom in C for encapsulating data.  There should be functions defined somewhere to allow you to manipulate items of type List_t without directly accessing the internals of the list.  You'll probably find you have something like `listNext(List_t)` or `listIterate(List_t)` defined somewhere.  Look in the same file as where `listCopy()` is declared.

Answer (score 2):

Move the definition of struct List_t to the .h file.

The list_example_test.c does not have a definition of struct List_t, it only knows that it's a struct (from the .h file), so the compiler has no way to calculate the offset to the "head" member of the List_t.

Comment: i know it would work that way, but the thing is that i cant change the .h file because this is a homework(we are not allowed to change it). there must be some way...

Comment: @Yanal: if you can't change the header then you must only use methods declared there to manipulate `List`: it's an opaque data structure, you (i.e. your main program) doesn't know how it looks.